# Objects are half transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I've been using blender for 1 year now, but I didn't see this such a thing in Cycles Render Mode

[image]

I had this problem 6 months ago and I somehow fixed it, but I forgot how

Can you guys help me to fix this problem? Here's the .blend file : https://pasteall.org/blend/a75ddb2e5ba74ef0aefecffb7b6bceaa  -- Blender v2.8.3, Cycles

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (copy paste here the URL it will give once uploaded)? https://pasteall.org/blend/